# network drive replaced by an external drive

Tags: networking, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have an old software which needs access to a network drive, eg. \\nameofnetworkdrive but the problem is that the network drive has now been replaced by an external USB drive (eg. drive X). Is there any way to create a symbolic link so that when the software tries to access \\nameofnetworkdrive it will in fact access from the new external drive X: instead? In other words, to trick the software into thinking that the network drive still exist but in fact it has been replaced by external drive X:?

I have tried to make the external drive X: as a network drive and try to use the same name as the previous network drive but this doesn't work because windows will automatically use the machine name of my computer as the first part of the name of the network drive, eg. \\computer name\nameofnetworkdrive

I am using an old Windows Vista. Grateful if anyone can show me what commands I can use in MS DOS to make this link.

Thank you!

===========UPDATED QUESTION=================================

Following the response I have received, I have created the network drive by the following:-

net share nameofnetworkdrive=X:

However, it has created a network drive with the name \\mycomputer\nameofnetworkdrive

Is there any way of making this network name to be \\nameofnetworkdrive without the mention of mycomputer? because the old software would only work if it can find a network drive with the name \\nameofnetworkdrive.

Grateful for any help on this! Thanks!

===================CURRENT PROBLEM===========

It would be easier if I explain the current problem. When I net share the external drive say X:, the path of such network drive will be called \[name of my computer][name that I create for this network drive]. Problem is my old software will only recognise a standalone network drive called \[name of network drive] but not one which is preceded by \[my computer]. The only way of course is to put the external drive into the network via an ethernet port (which is not possible because this drive does not have an ethernet port). As long as the external drive is plugged into my computer as an external drive when sharing the drive to the network its path will be preceded by the name of mycomputer. I am trying to find ways of getting rid of that path to mycomputer and making the drive as a stand alone network drive as if it was connected directly into the network via ethernet port. Hope this explains the problem. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have tried the command and created the network drive but the name of the network drive is now called \\mycomputer\test (using the same names as in your response) but the old software needs the network drive to be called \\test Is there anyway of changing the name so that the network drive is only referred to as \\test and without the computername? Thanks!

Comment: In Windows, shared folders are accessed by system name, share name and resource - for example `\\computer\shared` or `\\computer\shared\file.txt`... `\\computer` has never been a valid UNC path for a directory - are you sure there isn't a particular structure of shared folders that the software requires too, and which it then concatenates onto the "_base_" path `\\computer`?

Comment: the previous old network drive was a stand alone network drive plugged into the ethernet, so there was no \\computer\... in front of the path. It was simply \\\networkdrivename. I am trying to create a new network drive with such same name \\\networkdrivename but I can't because the \\\mycomputername is now always in front.

Comment: That's not how it works...

Answer (score 0):

You may create a share from an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) with the
[net share command](https://ss64.com/nt/net-share.html).

For example:

```
net share test=C:\Temp
dir \\mycomputer\test
```

This should also be possible from Windows Explorer
(but I don't remember the menu command on Vista).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I will look up this command to learn more about it  and give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried the command and created the network drive but the name of the network drive is now called \\mycomputer\test (using the same names as in your response) but the old software needs the network drive to be called \\test      Is there anyway of changing the name so that the network drive is only referred to as \\test and without the computername? Thanks!

Comment: That syntax never worked on any Windows version, since test will be taken as the name of a computer. Are you sure?

Comment: Because of the word limit in this comment box, I have described the problem as an update to my question above. Thanks.

Comment: I never heard of the syntax of "\\share", even in Vista. This was always "\\computer". Maybe the old program expects such a computer to exist on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Vista in a while, but this should still work if memory serves correctly.

Right-Click on My Computer > Manage > Disk Manager
Right-Click on the USB drive and choose "Change Drive Letter and Paths..."
Click Change, choose a new letter from the drop down, and then click OK.  Your USB drive should no longer be using that letter.

Edit:
Sorry, didn't read your post fully.  Try this: In your hosts file, (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

```
127.0.0.1   nameofnetworkdrive
```

Now when you use: `\\nameofnetworkdrive` it should point to your local machine.  You'll need to share out the local drive to do this.

Comment: Thanks but your method will allow change to the name of the drive. But in my case, the network drive is named as \\\mycomputer\networkdrivename but I want the name to be without mycomputer and be just \\\networkdrivename.

Comment: Thanks! I missed your edited response. I will try it now.

Comment: Did my update help you resolve your issue?